# Yii HumHub Inject Event into Main App

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to attach a event to a global scope of a Yii application called [HumHub](https://humhub.org/) however, when I try to run a function through the "TopMenu" which is global, it doesn't appear to do anything. Possibly because I'm not using the `$event` variable scope?

I am trying to make a development mode module to prevent access to anyone but administrators from viewing the system when it's activated. The only global way I know to get my code across all pages (with my limited understanding of HumHub and Yii) is the TopMenu as it appears on all pages (besides login page which is disabled when guest mode is active)

**autostart.php**

```
Yii::app()->moduleManager->register(array(
    'id' => 'devmode',
    'class' => 'application.modules.devmode.DevModeModule',
    'import' => array(
        'application.modules.devmode.*',
    ),
    // Events to Catch 
    'events' => array(
        array('class' => 'AdminMenuWidget', 'event' => 'onInit', 'callback' => array('DevModeEvents', 'onAdminMenuInit')),
        array('class' => 'TopMenuWidget', 'event' => 'onInit', 'callback' => array('DevModeEvents', 'devBlock')),
        array('class' => 'DashboardSidebarWidget', 'event' => 'onInit', 'callback' => array('DevModeModule', 'onSidebarInit')),
        ),
));
```

**DevModeEvents.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Defines the module events
 *
 * @package humhub.modules.devmode.events
 * @author Jordan Thompson
 */

class DevModeEvents {

    public static function onAdminMenuInit($event)
    {
        $event->sender->addItem(array(
            'label' => Yii::t('devmode.base', 'Development Mode'),
            'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('//devmode/config/config'),
            'group' => 'settings',
            'icon' => '<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>',
            'isActive' => (Yii::app()->controller->module && Yii::app()->controller->module->id == 'devmode' && Yii::app()->controller->id == 'admin'),
            'sortOrder' => 300,
        ));

    }   

    public static function devBlock($event) {

        $devMode = HSetting::Get('devMode', 'devmode');
        if ($devMode == 1 ) {
            if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
                if (!Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()) {
                    throw new CHttpException('418', Yii::t('devmode.base', Yii::app()->name . ' is currently under maintenance, check back later.'));
                }
            } else {
                throw new CHttpException('418', Yii::t('devmode.base', Yii::app()->name . ' is currently under maintenance, check back later.'));
            }
        } 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

change the sort order to 1, and access to it using css

```
li:nth-child(1) {
    //do something;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. There is no HTML rendering from the code to access CSS of it.